# Delete resource with references

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Hi I have a stack that create a cognito user pool and as part of it I export some outputs in order to cross referencd the stack via importing the export value, but when I try delete the template that export the names and I have already some users using the export values AWS throws an error that states that I cannot delete the recource because the references, so I think is a flaw in the design because I am reference by name an as I understand we may have the case we want to delete the resource and create it again and that is the reason of the export name to not be attached to a specific resource, but now I think under the hood it is attached to a specific resource even though we named, so I was wondering if there is a work around to do this otherwise I think this is not a production ready feature maybe? or I am using incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't delete or update (with replacement) a stack which exports its outputs (from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html)):

> After another stack imports an output value, you **can't delete** the stack that is exporting the output value or **modify** the exported output value. All of the imports must be removed before you can delete the exporting stack or modify the output value.

This is not a "flaw in the design ". This is by design. If you could delete stacks that have their outputs imported by others, it would lead to a lot of broken infrastructure and trouble.

Thus, when you export and import, you make **strong commitment** that the exporting stack will always be there for as long as its outputs are being used.

If you prefer to **loosely couple** your stacks without such commitment, then you should not use export/import. Instead you provide the outputs of the first stack as **input parameters** into the second stack. This makes your architecture loosely coupled and usually allows you to freely deleted/modify any of the stacks.

Comment: I got your point but still I think there will be some cases that we need to delete or update the stack that export and recreate it again but I got your point and if the documentation itself states that I supose I will need to check the drawbacks because if I use as parameters I will be loose coupling between stacks but Hard to replicate to múltiples environments but now I will be strong couple with a given resources because I will need to pass the id of the resource as the parameter

Comment: @jam I understand. But that's how it works sadly. AWS made the decision that you can't delete such stacks. There is not much you can do about that. But you can use other Infrastructure as Code tools, such as Terraform, if CloudFormation does not suit you.